# Want to send response using web socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

As the function is doing 2 things at one time. Firstly it is uploading data into database than it is retrieving data and displaying in fron page .All i need is I want to send response using websocket to front end that data has been uploaded successfully in db and now its going to display  the data
**Backend Code:**

```
loginrouter.get('/getImages',cors(),(req,res)=>{
  
  var array = fs.readFileSync('log.txt').toString().split("\n");
  for(i in array) {
    var sql = "INSERT into images (urls) values ('"+array[i]+"')";
    connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
      if (!err) {
        var sql = " SELECT urls FROM `images`";

        connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
          if (!err) {
            const wss = new WebSocketServer.Server({ port: 8081 })

            wss.on("connection", (ws,r) => {
              ws.send('This is a message to client');
            });
            res.send(result)
          } 
        });
      }
      })
  }
})[Here is the result snippet al i need is that when the data is fully uploaded in database a web socket should send a message that the data is uploaded successfully and now we are going to retrieve it][1]
```

Front end code:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <button type="button" onclick="getImage(event)" > Show Images</button><br />
    <h1 style="text-align: center; color: blue">Here are the Results:</h1>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.2.1/axios.js"
      integrity="sha512-SXo2rCaEJmbAPoxtaSjW+/hLaVCMAJ1CX8XnIP02x6/LIaWQp4GipKxQhBwL8Tn5U/K+lD9AaM4f4mXJdKnDQw=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    ></script>
    <script>
      function getImage(e) {
        var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8000", "dummyProtocol");
        exampleSocket.onopen = function (event) {
        exampleSocket.send("WebSocket is really cool");
        };


        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("hii");
        axios
          .get(
            "http://localhost:8000/getImages",
            {},
            {
              headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            }
          )
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
            for (let i = 0; i < 850; i++) {
              console.log(response.data[i].urls)
              document.getElementById(
                "demo"
              ).innerHTML += `<img src="${response.data[i].urls}" style="border:1px solid black;margin-bottom:4px;margin-top:14px; margin-right: 20px" width="100px" height="100px"
    alt="img">`;
            }
          });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't connect with ws to http server port

```js
var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8000", "dummyProtocol");
```

2. Create an instance of ws server outside the route

```js
loginrouter.get('/getImages'
```

3. After you uploaded your data to database, send response to the user by http that the work was done, and here you have two ways to send data by ws to user.

3.1 User gets response by http that the work was done and send a request by ws to retrieve some data.

3.2 at route  getImages after sending http response, send data by ws if user already connected.
Something like this. It's not working code, only the way where you can go.

```js
const clients = new Map();
const wss = new WebSocketServer.Server({ port: 8081 })

wss.on("connection", (ws,r) => {
    ws.send('This is a message to client');
    const id = uuidv4();
    clients.set(id, ws);
});

loginrouter.get('/getImages',cors(),(req, res)=>{
    connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (!err) {
            res.send(result);
            clients.get(req.cookies.id).send(what_you_want_to_send)
        } 
    });
})
```

Comment: is it possbile to send the websocket response in the same route??

Comment: Because there is no specific user affiliated with it all process that is happeing here is sending data to database and retiering data from database at the same time

Comment: I want to add just one thing when the data will be uploaded web socket will display the message on front end that the data has been uploaded

Comment: @f180111YousafZahid At first, you ca not send http response more than one time as you do it in the loop. You should accumulate the result into array or object and then send it at once.

Comment: @f180111YousafZahid Client should connect with ws at first, set the client id . Only after that request data by  axios with id at cookies  that you recieved by ws. Then use it at your route to send message to client by ws as i've wrote upper.

Comment: @f180111YousafZahid if after that all you want to send a message by ws only once, then you need to send it after your loop at the route getImages. Use async database qeury methods https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_async.asp . With callbacks it will not be  nice.

Comment: not able to get any single clue to handle it.. doing it for the very first time

Comment: can you please elaborate with some sort of syntax as well beacuse i am totally blank about it i cannot get the client id as well and dont know how to access it on front end etc etc